# Deciding whether a number is rational (2 examples)

Tags: irrational-numbers

1) Prove that number irrational $\sqrt{7-\sqrt{2}}$

I created a polynomial $x=\sqrt{7-\sqrt{2}}$ so

$P(x)=x^4-14x^2+47$ and since $47$ is prime we check $P(x)$ for $ {1,-1,47,-47}$ and since all of them are $P(x)\neq0$ it means our number is irrational.

Is my prof OK ?

2) Decide if the number $\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+3}+\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}$ is rational or irrational. I don't know how to tackle this one. I'd be grateful for hints

Comment: The approach in your first proof is correct, though it could be a bit more polished: $P(x)$ certainly has this number as a root, and then you apply the Rational Root Theorem. As for the second, think about how you created the polynomial in 1) so that it'd include that root.

Comment: 1) That's the correct idea, but check your numbers.

Comment: 2) Since there are four square-roots, I suspect the polynomial is going to be degree $2^4=16$!

Comment: Whenever tasked with a proof like this, you can be pretty sure that your working to a point where a known irrational number equals an integer over an integer (i.e. rational), which is a contradiction -> QED.

Comment: It should be $P(x) \equiv x^4 - 14 x^2 \color{red}{+ 47}$ and not $-47$ there.

Comment: If you square your number, you get 7 - sqrt (2) which is irrational. Squaring a rational produces a rational, so you must have squared an irrational number.

Comment: http://joaomaths.blogspot.com.au/2014/07/proof-that-solutions-to-xnan-1xn-1an.html see this proof and then try to show that your expression isn't an integer.

Comment: I corrected the error reported by @hjpotter92

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For 2).

If $p=\sqrt{\sqrt 5+3}+\sqrt{\sqrt 5-2}$ is a rational number, then
$$\begin{align}p-\sqrt{\sqrt5+3}=\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}&\Rightarrow p^2-2p\sqrt{\sqrt5+3}+\sqrt5+3=\sqrt5-2\\&\Rightarrow 2p\sqrt{\sqrt5+3}=p^2+5\\&\Rightarrow 4p^2(\sqrt 5+3)=(p^2+5)^2\\&\Rightarrow \sqrt5=\frac{(p^2+5)^2}{4p^2}-3\end{align}$$
implies that $\sqrt 5$ is a rational number. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Very smooth! I am curious - can the irrationality of all algebraic irrationals, no matter how complex the number, be demonstrated by this "inductive" method (given the irrationality of all prime roots is a given) or are there any exceptions?

Comment: @Just_a_fool The reason that the trick works here is that the 'inner' roots are the same, so after two squaring steps you're left with a single square root.  OTOH, the method that you used for 1) (with the rational root theorem) can be used as an algorithm to determine the rationality or irrationality of an arbitrary algebraic expression (since the equation gives you a finite number of possible values to test against and all roots can be computed to sufficient precision).  OTOH, there's a lot of subtlety in this; look up the 'sum-of-square-roots' problem in computational geometry for details..

Answer (score 36):

You don't need all that! If $\sqrt{7-\sqrt 2} = \dfrac{p}{q}$ is rational, then $\sqrt 2 = 7 - \dfrac{p^2}{q^2}$is rational. Which it isn't.